# Mapping through array to display images

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-native

```
const SingelProduct = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(props.route.params.item);
  // const [availability , setAvailability] = useState('');

  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={{ marginBottom: 80, padding: 5 }}>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: item.image
                ? item.image
                : 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31iUt+FGBhL._AC_.jpg',
            }}
            resizeMode='contain'
            style={styles.image}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <H1 style={styles.contentHeader}>{item.name}</H1>
          <Text style={styles.contantText}>{item.brand}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: 600 }}>
          {item.images.map((item) => {
            return <Image source={{ uri: item.images }} key={item._id} />;
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <Left>
          <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price}Dhs</Text>
        </Left>
        <Right>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button
              title='Add To Card'
              color={'#47A73E'}
              onPress={() => {
                props.addItemToCart(item);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </Right>
      </View>
    </Container>
  );
};


{ 
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "1"
        },
        "name": "Tesla",
        "description": ""
        "image": "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/WOyZj/s1/4x3/tesla-model-3-18-aero-wheels-design-studio-u.s.---october-2020.webp",
        "images": ["https://sc04.alicdn.com/kf/Hea0b6d0488ce4e49baec94c451ba83a9z.png","https://sc04.alicdn.com/kf/Hea0b6d0488ce4e49baec94c451ba83a9z.png"],
        "brand": "Model 3",
        "price": 118000,
        "countInStock": 220,
        "category": {
            "$oid": "1"
          },
        "isFeatured": true,
        "dateCreated": "2022-06-03T12:06:39.158Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Comment: error :  <View style={{height:600}}>
                {item.images.map((item)=> {
                    return (
                      <Image source={{uri:item.images 
                    }} key={item._id} />
                    )
                })}
                
            </View>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height`, `width` and `resizeMode` to the style of mapped Image